# Кодировка в подписи письма

Tags: php, кодировка, email

Приветствую всех вошедших

```
$to  = "***@ya.ru" ;
$subject = "Текст 1"; 
$message = ' 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Текст 2</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
Текст 3
</body> 
</html>
'; 
$headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 \r\n"; 
$headers .= "From: Текст 4 <no-reply@my-site.ru>\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Bcc: no-reply@my-site.ru\r\n"; 
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Собственно отсылаю вот такое письмо. Оно ест-но доходит. В списке писем отображается нормально (по крайней мере на яндексе). Если же зайти в само письмо - есть 1 неточность. Там где написано от кого (в самом верху), в место 'Текст 4' отображаются караказябры.

Кодировка в .htaccess utf-8, в файле который отправляет тоже, и в письме. Куда дальше копать?

Comment: т.е. в теле нормальные русские буквы? )

Comment: В списке емайлов - нормальные. Если зайти в сам email - каракозябры. 8-(

Comment: почитайте http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2047 и дополняющий его http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5335#section-4.1 

http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6532#section-3.1

Comment: Огх.. Брррр.. Как надеялся, что не дадите мне ссылку на эту статью! Сам на нее вышел вчера, думал есть уже что то готовое и придуманное. Ладно. пойду разбираться

Answer (score 1):

Должен помочь следующий код, который сам неоднократно использовал:

```
$headers .= "From: =?UTF-8?B?" . base64_encode('Текст 4') . "?= <no-reply@my-site.ru>\r\n";
```

Посмотрите примеры из комментариев к [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php#108669)

`=?` - начало описания
`UTF-8?` - указатель на кодировку текста
`B?` - указатель на то, что текст закодирован в BASE64
`?=` - конец описания

**[Пример в RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047#section-8)**